# Apply MacBuntu Boot-screen/Splash in Ubuntu 16

Tags: boot

After installing the MacBuntu transformation pack for my Ubuntu 16, when I boot my computer, the MacBuntu Boot-screen/Splash does not come. The apple logo does not show and I don't know why.

Comment: Your question does not make sense.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu you are saying that after your installed the pack, the apple logo does not show up, then this question is not related to Ubuntu. Please ask it on [Ask Different](apple.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 1):

You might need to update the Plymouth to change the boot screen.

Run the following commands

```
    sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

After the first command is executed it will ask you to select a Plymouth theme. Type in the number corresponding to the Macbuntu related Plymouth theme and hit enter. Next run the second command and after it is executed completely reboot the system to see changes.

Comment: thanks but this is what happens anytime i try it in the terminal

Comment: bra@bra-inspiron:~$ sudo update-initramfs -u
sudo: unable to resolve host bra-inspiron: Connection timed out
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
sudo update-initramfs -u

Answer (score 1):

run

```
sudo gedit /etc/hosts
sudo gedit /etc/hostname
```

and verify that hostnames are same in both files.

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
127.0.1.1    <your_hostname@your_host>
```

If not edit, save the file and then reboot. This will solve yor unable to verify hostname issue.

Ensure that you have installed macbuntu splashscreen in their transformation pack by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install macbuntu-os-bscreen-lts-v7
```

After that you can run

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/share/plymouth/themes/default.plymouth default.plymouth /usr/share/plymouth/themes/macbuntu/macbuntu.plymouth 100
```

here you are installing macbuntu splash screen you have installed with the transformation pack as a plymouth alternative.

The format is 
`update-alternatives --install <link> <symlink name> <path> <priority>`

Now run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

and Reboot.

Answer (score -1):

You need to open the `macbuntu.plymouth` file and change the locations under `[script]`. Change every instance of "`/lib`" to "`usr/share`," being that apparently Ubuntu usually lacks the `/lib` files needed for this module, but you can redirect them to the existing ones in the `/usr/share` directory. Works every time for me.

`sudo gedit /usr/share/plymouth/themes/macbuntu/macbuntu.plymouth`

[macbuntu.plymouth (Fixed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzVhF.png)

Comment: Why the downvote? Every single time I've installed this (over 35 times), this is what I do and it always, *always* works...